# Верстка элементов через border

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно сверстать стрелку с закругленными углами, я реализовал её через бордер, но бордер-радиус не применяется где нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получается только такая, не все углы могу скруглить...

```css
.prev {
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  right: 0;
  border: 8px solid #4a275c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="prev"></div>
```

Comment: У меня такое получалось двумя линиями в `:before` и `:after`, долго ковырялся с аналогичной проблемой, но решение только такое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например можно так:

```css
.prev {
  position: relative;
}

.prev:before,
.prev:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    width: 32px;
    background: #4a275c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}

.prev:before {
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.prev:after {
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="prev"></div>
```

Если в обратную сторону:

```css
.prev {
  position: relative;
}

.prev:before,
.prev:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    width: 32px;
    background: #4a275c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}

.prev:before {
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.prev:after {
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="prev"></div>
```

Comment: А не подскажите, как в обратную сторону такую же сделать? что-то не получается по аналогии

Comment: @Александр, добавила и для обратной стороны!

Comment: Только я сделал бы для обратной по такой логике: `.arrow {...}` + `.arrow.next { transform: rotate(180deg) }`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.prev {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;  
}
.prev:before,
.prev:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; left: 15px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #4a275c;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.prev:before{
  top: 0;  
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.prev:after{
  top: 18px; 
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="prev"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

А а если попробовать через `after` и `before` создать две линии скруглить их полностью и потом трансформацией развернуть.